# atomically writing to a socket

Tags: sockets, emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm using `process-send-string` to send data to a socket connection, but I'm not satisfied with the effect of this function. Roughly, calling `(process-send-string "foo")` may end up in sending `"bar"` and then `"foo"`, as explained below.

As pointed out by Emacs maintainers, the C code of `process-send-string` calls a function `wait_reading_process_output` (even before actually writing anything), which may run timers, which in turn may call `process-send-string`, and no ordering is enforced between such nested calls.

This makes it virtually impossible to implement an RPC protocol which is intended to be used by hooks called at uncontrolled times. So my question is, how could we achieve an atomic, "synchronized" writing primitive for this purpose ?

Comment: Have you actually experienced that effect? Having a glance at Emacs' source code, it seems that the case you describe could arise when the data cannot be written to the socket in one batch, but requires multiple calls to `sendto'. After each of these calls, `wait_reading_process_output' is called to handle keyboard events and redisplays. It is not clear to me how the timers used within that function could call `process-send-string' again.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the following: sending m1, m2, m3, the connection end receives m2, m3, m1.

Comment: Note that TCP is byte oriented, not packet oriented. If the application writes "1234", the TCP stack may send this in any possible segmentation, eg "12", "3", "4". If you want to run a protocol above TCP, you must find define a way to find the boundaries of your messages, eg. by using a length field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, an option that worked for me was to use the transaction queue API, which is higher level (so it cannot handle all sorts of protocols), but ensures correct ordering of alternating messages.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
(defun my-send-cmd (proc str)
  (if (process-get proc 'my-waiting)
      (process-put proc 'my-pending (append (process-get proc 'my-pending) (list str)))
    (process-put proc 'my-waiting t)
    (process-send-string proc str)))
```

then in the process-filter, when you get the answer to a command, check `my-pending' and if non-nil, take the first arg, send it to the process, otherwise set my-waiting back to nil.
Of course, this assumes that every command will get an answer from the server, and that you can't stream the commands.

This said, the behavior you see should probably count as a bug, or at least as a misfeature, so please report it with M-x report-emacs-bug.

Comment: This seems to work: the protocol communication still works and I cannot observe (the consequences of) a message swap anymore, so I guess you just saved my life by solving this major issue on hour from the release :-)

Comment: The idea of using the process-filter as a "sending thread" was what I was missing, and work well here as I always have alternating messages.

Comment: And about a bug report, I sent one, got some short feedback, but I'm still unsure whether it is considered a bug, misfeature or none. I'll make sure to get a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using process-send-string directly in your hooks, append to a buffer, then have the process-send-string calls run in a way that is not asynchronous.

Comment: "have the process-send-string calls run in a way that is not asynchronous" how ?